# Am I interpreting Visual Studio assembly output correctly?

Tags: c++, assembly, output

I was just curious as to whether these two lines of code differ:

```
bool done = false;
bool done(false);
```

It seems that the second would be faster as in the first case we call the default constructor, then assign the value. Whereas in the second we only call the constructor.

(Maybe this should be its own question?)

I stuck in a breakpoint and had a look at the assembler output for both lines. They are exactly the same:

```
    bool done = false;
00F66E7D  mov         byte ptr [done],0
```

Am I right in concluding therefore that the two lines are the same, or at-least the compiler is optimizing one of them?

Is this the correct way to work something like this out?

Comment: Scalar types do not have constructors.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ahh, okay. Since the syntax matches that of a constructor in line 2 I understood that's what it was. Guess that's not the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 bool done = false;
 bool done(false);
```

> It seems that the second would be faster as in the first case we call the default constructor, then assign the value. Whereas in the second we only call the constructor.

No. In the first case you technically create a temporary `bool` value and use a copy of that to initialize `done`. However, all compilers will optimize out the copying and initialize `done` directly. And it is not default initialized first.

In the second case, you are using a direct initialization of `done`. No copies are created.

Of course, for a `bool` value this makes no difference.

The only difference you will see for some `class` types is that if copying is disabled (with `= delete`), the first version will not compile (even though the compiler is allowed to optimize out any copies for class objects as well). If it compiles, the resulting code will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` is a fundamental integral type in C++. It does not have a constructor and the lines are exactly the same. There is also no need for optimization since the operation is a simple assignment of zero.

Comment: Ahh, okay. How about if we replaced bool with a user-defined type? Is line 1 slower than line 2 then? Also, regarding the assembler output, is this the correct way to see if action A is faster/slower than action B?